# DSC SMB Pullserver - clients are unable to locate mof file

Tags: dsc

I have configured the LCM of my target node like this:

```
[DSCLocalConfigurationManager()]
configuration SMBPullClientConfig
{
param
(   
    [PARAMETER(Mandatory=$false)]
    $NodeName = 'localhost',
    [PARAMETER(Mandatory=$true)]
    $GUID,
    [PARAMETER(Mandatory=$true)]
    [STRING]$SMBShare
)

    Node $NodeName
    {
        Settings
        {
            RefreshMode = 'Pull'
            ConfigurationID = "6b280c54-2706-4fd3-bb9a-bf6774f4cc35"
        }
        ConfigurationRepositoryShare SmbConfigurationShare
        {
            SourcePath = $SmbShare         
        }

        ResourceRepositoryShare SMBResource
        {
            SourcePath = $SmbShare        
        }        

    }
}
```

after that i generate my meta.mof will and applied it to the lcm:

```
SMBPullClientConfig -GUid "6b280c54-2706-4fd3-bb9a-bf6774f4cc35" -SmBshare "\\10.254.41.94\SMBPull" -OutputPath C:\Configs\metamofs
Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager -Path C:\Configs\metamofs
```

so far - no errors. in the repository there a both, a *6b280c54-2706-4fd3-bb9a-bf6774f4cc35.mof* and a *6b280c54-2706-4fd3-bb9a-bf6774f4cc35.mof.checksum*.

I can address this file from trarget node by using powershell:

```
test-path -path "\\10.254.41.94\SMBPull\6b280c54-2706-4fd3-bb9a-bf6774f4cc35.mof".
```

this command returns a true.
In the last step i try to use the configuration:

```
update-DSCConfiguration
```

This generates a background job that failed.
The output from 'Receive-job':

```
file \\10.254.41.94\SMBPull\6b280c54-2706-4fd3-bb9a-bf6774f4cc35.mof is not found.
```

What happened ? i have no idea,
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Double check who the configuration job is running as, and whether that has access to the remote share.  I assume you did the test-path as yourself?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an authentication issue with share while the LCM on target machine tries to access it. A workaround for this issue is to add target computers in a Security Group and give this Security Group Read Access to the SMB_Share.